# ScriptManager - RegisterStartupScript ( with 2 parameters)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I learn ASP.net and C#,
I want to call a JS function , from C#.
This is the function in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function open(x,y) 
     {
         alert(x);             
     }
</script>
```

and this is the line from C# (when Allcc is a string):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Pop", String.Format("openModal('{0}{1}{2}');",0,",", Allcc), true);
```

I have to transfer 2 parameters(1- number 0 . 2- Allacc (string)), but actually I get only one string . what Should I change to send both of the parameters separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are enclosing all the values in one pair of single quotes. The current call would be like `"openModal('0,valueOfAllcc');"` To pass two parameters you need to use two pairs of single `quotes`

```
String.Format("openModal('{0}'{1}'{2}');",0,",", Allcc)
```

I think you have `openModal` instead of `open` in `javascript` as you are calling `openModal`.